# Atom Package: hide developer keys

Tags: javascript, git, atom-editor

I am working on an Atom Package. It needs a developer key to work.

I would like to avoid committing the key. However, to publish an Atom Package, the code needs to be committed in a public repository.

The key is not really secret. Therefore, if it is bundled in the package is not a problem. I just don't want it to be committed in the public repository.

Is there a way to publish an Atom Package that needs a secret key without having to commit the secret key to the project's repository?

Comment: Add the key as its own file, and then include the key file in the .gitignore for that directory

Comment: Is the key secret or not secret? You say it's both in your question.
And It seems to me that atom's package manager simply pulls files from the git repository, so if every user who installs it needs the key for the package to work, and it's not in the repository, then how are they going to get the key otherwise? Unless it's a system where they need to supply their own key, in that case, use a .gitignore file

Comment: Developers need to supply their own key, but users don't need to. I want users to have a default secret key. It's a secret to the extent that someone could exploit this key to bust the api limit rates on the default account.
I don't want a GitHub scrapper from getting the key and abusing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most common way would probably a package setting that lets your users enter the key.

**Example:**

```
// main.js
export const config = {
  developerKey: {
    title: 'Developer Key',
    description: 'Specify your developer key or [sign up](https://) to get one',
    type: 'string',
    default: ''
  }
};
```

To get the developer key, you can query using `atom.config.get`:

```
atom.config.get(your-package-name.developerKey');
```

See the [Atom API Documentation](https://atom.io/docs/api/v1.8.0/Config) for details.